# Replacement for Unnest transform

Tags: java, apache-beam

Up until Beam 2.19, there was a transform called [org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Unnest](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/Unnest.html).  After that release, the transform seems to have been removed.  I am looking for documentation / guides on its replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Unnest was replaced by [Select](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/Select.html) in https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10766/.

There is a test case that does the following:

```
    PCollection<Row> unnested =
        pipeline
            .apply(Create.of(rows).withRowSchema(SIMPLE_SCHEMA))
            .apply(Select.flattenedSchema());
```

Can you please verify if `Select.flattenedSchema` does what you are expecting?